# rmdir favorites Access is Denied

Tags: windows-10, command-line, batch, dir, rmdir

Command prompt:

`CD C:\Users\Example\`

`rmdir favorites`

> Access is denied.

How do I delete the Favorites folder via the command prompt?

- *Yes*, I want to do this.
- *Yes*, I know this folder is for Internet Explorer.
- *Yes*, I manually delete this folder all of the time without any issues.
- *No*, the My Documents folder is *my* folder, not Microsoft's.

**Edit 1:**

I added "Everyone" as a user with all permissions for S&G:

[image: Folder Permissions]

**Edit 2:**

```
icacls Favorites
Favorites S-1-15-3-4096:(OI)(CI)(RX,W,DC)
          Everyone:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
          NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
          DESKTOP-DM38CA6\John:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
          BUILTIN\Administrators:(I)(OI)(CI)(F)
          Mandatory Label\Low Mandatory Level:(OI)(CI)(NW)

Successfully processed 1 files; Failed processing 0 files
```

**Answer**

Thanks to people's comments and S. Brottes's answer here are the batch commands:

```
cd C:\Users\Example\Favorites
attrib desktop.ini -h -s
del desktop.ini
cd..
rmdir /s /q favorites
```

Comment: Are you logging-in as the user that owns the folder, or at least as administrator? Is CMD run as Administrator?

Comment: @harrymc I always run local admin accounts for Windows. Also I tested the admin permissions command prompt and same issue.

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of the Security tab after right-click in Explorer of the folder and selecting Properties?

Comment: @harrymc Which folder? C:\Users\Example\?

Comment: Yes, the one you have a problem with.

Comment: @harrymc Updated and I added "Everyone" for the moment. I'm the only person with physical access so I'm not worried about that at the moment. Still, the same problem.

Comment: can you show output of `icacls Favorites`

Comment: @S.Brottes Edit #2 is up.

Comment: Have you tried `rmdir /s favorites`?

Comment: @harrymc The answer failed in a batch (works fine manually) however `rmdir /s /q favorites` fixes the automated batch! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some default folder like "Favorites" have "Read Only" attributes.

You can check the attributes with the following command

```
attrib Favorites
```

This attribute prevents to delete the folder.

You can remove the read only attribute with the following command :

```
attrib -R Favorites
```

Then you should be able to remove the directory with the `rmdir` command.

The folder must be empty, or you must use the `/s` param to delete all elements of the folder.

Comment: Cool, after using `attrib -R Favorites` then `rmdir favorites` resulted in "The directory is not empty.". Unhide system files and there is a desktop.ini file (for the custom folder icon). I used `attrib desktop.ini -h` to unhide and it returned "Not resetting system file". I'll post the full working answer though because I figured it from you I'll accept yours.

Comment: When files have System attribute AND Hidden attribute, you must remove the two attributes in the same time in order to make it work. You can use the following command: `attrib -h -s <filename>`

Comment: I should note that `rmdir /s /q C:\Users\John\Favorites` the two switches are necessary for the *automated batch* whereas everything else works perfectly during a *manual* command prompt.